# Mutiple Form Submission Failing to Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, asp-classic, form-submit

Can someone help me please.  I had replies to a similar question but am unable to solve my problem so I have tried to be as detailed as I can here.  Sorry if it's a repeat but I am really in need of help on this.

I am trying to submit three forms to the same asp page via a mouseover event.  The asp page executes code to save an image according to which form was submitted and the data it contains.  I have tried several ways to do this.  Submitting in turn as shown below results in some or all of the images being created, but it is random and it seems subsequent submissions are overwriting previous calls.

```
function save_all_des(){
    document.getElementById("form_zoom1").submit();
    document.getElementById("form_zoom2").submit();
    document.getElementById("form_zoom3").submit();
}
```

I have also tried using jquery like this:

```
$("#create_image").mouseover(function() {
    $("#form_zoom1").submit(function() {
    $("#form_zoom2").submit(function() {
    $("#form_zoom3").submit();
    });
    });
});
```

This doesn't work at all, even if I try just one form. (The mouseover event itself fires ok.)

The three forms have the same input names (I've shown just one) but with different values.  Individually they submit ok.

```
<form id="form_zoom1" name="form_zoom1"  action="abc.asp" target="MyFrame">
    <input type="hidden" name="tab" value="1">
</form>
<form id="form_zoom2" name="form_zoom2"  action="abc.asp" target="MyFrame2">
    <input type="hidden" name="tab" value="2">
</form>
<form id="form_zoom3" name="form_zoom3"  action="abc.asp" target="MyFrame3">
    <input type="hidden" name="tab" value="3">
</form>

<iframe id="MyFrame" name="MyFrame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<iframe id="MyFrame2" name="MyFrame2" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<iframe id="MyFrame3" name="MyFrame3" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

How do I make sure the code behind the one form submittal is fininshed before the second, then third, is submitted?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'd be better off using AJAX to send POST requests to the server, rather than actually submitting the form. You could possibly send all three requests at the same time, and have it work correctly, but that depends on exactly what you're doing with the response from the server after the submit.

Take a look at the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for more information on using it to perform AJAX calls.

Sample code may look something like this:

```
function submitForm(form) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'abc.asp',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            tab : $('input[name="tab"]',form).val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            /* handle the response from the server here
            if you don't need to do anything to the structure of the page, you can probably just leave this blank
            may want to put in some console.log or alert statements for debugging purposes
            */
        }
    });
}

$('#create_image').mouseover(function() {
    submitForm($('#form_zoom1'));
    submitForm($('#form_zoom2'));
    submitForm($('#form_zoom3'));
});
```

Note that that sends three AJAX POST requests, one for each form, at roughly the same time. There's no guarantee that they'll complete in that order (though this doesn't seem important given the information you've provided).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anthony. Unfortunately I'm new to javascript so jquery and AJAX are even newr to me.  The server creates an image and saves it to the server using some detailed asp code.  The user doesn't see anything change as far as they're concerned.  The image is then available to view through Lightbox.  Can you show me an example of what you suggest?  I fear that AJAX is beyond me at present.

Comment: @user1101686 I've edited the answer to include some jQuery code that may do what you want, given the information you've provided. It sends all three requests at (roughly) the same time, rather than waiting for the first one to complete before sending the next, though I don't think that's going to be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll try this out and let you know if I can get it to work.

Comment: Anthony.  I've used your code but I get a syntax error on the line 'tab : $....' . Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @Mark_54 Gah! Delete the semi-colon at the end of that line, it's not needed. My mistake - I'll edit the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried it again (and also using form.serialize) and it works fine in FF but only once in IE9 before you have to close and reopen the browser!  I've had the same issue with the only other time I tried AJAX.  Any ideas?

Comment: IE caches AJAX calls, so you'll need to either set the `cache` property to `false` on each call to `.ajax()` or add `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});` at the top of your script to set the `cache` property for all AJAX requests.

Comment: So is $.ajaxSetup({cache: false}); put as the first line in the function?

Comment: Anthony, to save you time... I've put the line in and IT WORKS!!! I can't thank you enough.  Furthermore, I had to stop [starting to} use AJAX because of the IE issue.  Many replies suggested passing randon variables etc, which I didn't know how to do.  If I'd only known your solution my code would be MUCH tidier.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Mark_54 I normally put it at the top of my external Javascript file(s) so that it gets called when the script is loaded, and I know that any AJAX calls I make using jQuery later on aren't going to be cached. If you're putting your jQuery code inside `<script>` tags in a HTML file, put it just after the opening tag (provided they're **after** jQuery has been loaded).